# Objective C: How to reload data in parent cell from subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, reload

I have a UITableView with each cell containing the following

1) A UILabel (listing the names of people who clicked on the button)

2) A button (when clicked will add the clicker's name to the list displayed in UILabel)

The button is an instance of a subclass of UIControl. So the intention is that when the button is clicked, I will add the current user to the array used by the UILabel for display.

However, I am unsure how I can reload the parent cell (in which the button is contained)

Just to re-iterate my issue

1) The addition of user name to list is done in the button subclass and not the UITableViewCell, how can I call the parent cell once I have updated the array?

2) I do not want to reload the entire table, just the specific cell in which the user has clicked the button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an action method in the view controller which is the table view datasource, like :

```
-(IBAction)reloadCell:(id)theCell {
   NSIndexPath *idxPath = [theTableView indexPathForCell:theCell];
   [theTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:idxPath, nil]
                        withRowAnimation:YES]; // or NO ;)
}
```

Then in the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method, before returning the cell, configure it like so :

```
// ...
[cell.theButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(reloadCell:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;
```

This will make the `-(IBAction)reloadCell:(id)sender;` method called when touching the button, and reloading the particular cell, but this solution will maybe make you move the code that updates the content of the list, as I don't know which of the messages will be sent first (the one updates the content, or the one that reloads the cell).

So the best way I think is, for your custom button subclass to have a weak reference to the controller, so the button could update the content, and then send a message to the controller, and is working based on the same action method in the controller.

**In your button subclass .h**

```
YourControllerType *tableController;

@property(assign) YourControllerType *tableController;
```

**In your button subclass .m**

```
@synthesize tableController

// in the method where you update the list
[tableController reloadCell:self.superview];
```

Also don't forget to configure correctly the cell

```
// ...
cell.theButton.tableController = self;
return cell;
```

Comment: little mistake, the first parameter for `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is a `NSArray`, sorry